# Strange error when converting from VB to C# TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider exception Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm

Tags: c#, vb.net, encryption, cryptography

I built a password encryption program in visual basic and am porting it to c# all of the code is correctly converted as far as i can see ive debugged the program up to the point that the error is thrown all the key sizes are the same in the VB app and in the c# app yet the c# version throws the exception.

Unhandled Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.

the only difference between the two is the declaration of the statement in a class for use at runtime.

vb

```
Private Wrapper As New EncryptionWrapper(key:=0)
```

however :=0 does not work in c# so i used :"" instead i think this may be the issue but i hope its not because im not sure the workaround.

c#

```
private EncryptionWrapper Wrapper = new EncryptionWrapper(Key:"");
```

oh and security broker is just the declaration for the TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider like so

```
private TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider SecurityBroker = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
```

Visual Basic :

```
''' <summary>
''' Class initializer to initialize the encryption wrapper with a new encryption password.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="key">Encryption password string.</param>
Sub New(ByVal key As String)
    'Initialize the crypto provider.
    SecurityBroker.Key = TruncateHash(key, SecurityBroker.KeySize \ 8) ' 196 - 24 (runtime values)
    SecurityBroker.IV = TruncateHash("", SecurityBroker.BlockSize \ 8) ' 64 - 8 (runtime values)
End Sub
```

c# :

```
//Class constructor
public EncryptionWrapper(string Key)
{
    SecurityBroker.Key = TruncateHash(Key, SecurityBroker.KeySize / 8);  //196 - 24
    SecurityBroker.IV = TruncateHash("", SecurityBroker.BlockSize / 8);  //64 - 8
}
```

more useful information:

truncate hash function in c#

```
        public byte[] TruncateHash(string Key, int length)
        {
            SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

            byte[] keyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Key);
            byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes);

            return (byte[])RedimPreserve(hash, hash.Length - 1);
        }

        //c# custom function to take place of ReDim from VB
        public static Array RedimPreserve(Array originArray, Int32 desiredSize)
        {
            System.Type t = originArray.GetType().GetElementType();
            Array newArray = Array.CreateInstance(t, desiredSize);
            Array.Copy(originArray, 0, newArray, 0, Math.Min(originArray.Length, desiredSize));
            return newArray;
        }
```

in vb

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Truncates the hash to remove extra characters from the beginning and end
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="key">Hash key</param>
    ''' <param name="length">Hash length</param>
    ''' <returns>A truncated hash byte array</returns>
    Private Function TruncateHash(ByVal key As String, ByVal length As Integer) As Byte()
        Dim sha1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

        'Hash the key.
        Dim keyBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key)
        Dim hash() As Byte = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes)

        'Truncate or pad the hash.
        ReDim Preserve hash(length - 1)
        Return hash
    End Function
```

Comment: `ComputeHash` has an overload that allows to specify what part of the array you want to take. Not exactly the right way to create that `Key` and `.IV`, though.

Comment: After a more in depth step through debug protocol, both of the return functions return an empty hash array with a size of 23 (24-1) the only difference being in c# the hash variable is null and in vb the hash variable is nothing. I thought null and nothing were equivalent in C# and vb

Comment: Pedantically speaking, `null` doesn't have an exact equivalent in VB.  The C# equivalent to the VB `Nothing` is `default`.  As a practical matter, though, I believe `Nothing` will end up being `null` in every context where `null` is valid.

Comment: Is your original VB compiled with `Option Strict On`?  You should not be able to write the same code as `Key:=0` on the VB side and `key:""` on the C# side.  The types are different (and, for that matter, the argument names are different too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the -1 in the resized array of the truncate hash function fixed the pro

```
public byte[] TruncateHash(string Key, int length)
        {
            SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

            byte[] keyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Key);
            byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes);

            Array.Resize(ref hash, length);

            return hash;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of funny VB stuff happening here:

1. VB allows you to pass the integer literal 0 to a string parameter.  The equivalent is not an empty string in C#, but the string literal "0".
2. This 'ReDim Preserve' converts trivially to Array.Resize.
3. The conversion of VB integer division (operator '\') needs an accompanying cast to ensure a truncated integer result (like VB).

i.e.,

```
using System;

internal class Test
{
    private EncryptionWrapper Wrapper = new EncryptionWrapper(key: "0");
}

internal class EncryptionWrapper
{

    public EncryptionWrapper(string key) // 196 - 24 (runtime values)
    {
        //Initialize the crypto provider.
        SecurityBroker.Key = TruncateHash(key, Convert.ToInt32(SecurityBroker.KeySize) / 8);
        SecurityBroker.IV = TruncateHash("", Convert.ToInt32(SecurityBroker.BlockSize) / 8); // 64 - 8 (runtime values)
    }

    private byte[] TruncateHash(string key, int length)
    {
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

        //Hash the key.
        byte[] keyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key);
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes);

        //Truncate or pad the hash.
        Array.Resize(ref hash, length);
        return hash;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/walkthrough-encrypting-and-decrypting-strings This is the reference for my code